# How to change 1d array to 2d array under certain conditions

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way through python numpy operations to produce the following result?

Input 1d array :

```
[3, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1]
```

Output 2d array :

```
3 0 0 2 2 1
0 0 0 2 2 1
0 0 0 2 2 1
2 2 2 2 2 1
2 2 2 2 2 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Make a `np.zeros((6,6), int)`, and assign your 1d array to it using slices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the input array always contains increasing values, you can use `np.maximum(arr[None,:], arr[:, None])`. This compute the maximum of `arr[i]` and `arr[j]` for all items at the location `(i, j)` of the output array thanks to Numpy broadcasting. If the input does not always contains increasing values, then the out needs to be better defined.

Answer (score 5):

in addition to jeromie’s brilliant answer, here is a support for unordered array:

```
indexes = np.arange(len(arr))
idx = np.maximum(indexes[None,:], indexes[:, None])
arr[idx]
```

Comment: Why should Jerome's answer be accepted when it doesn't do what OP asked? Yours does...

Comment: @ddejohn because the question changed in the meantime. I just wondered the same and checked the history ;)

Comment: anyways this solution partially taken from the accepted answer i think justice was done

Answer (score 1):

Adir's solution is brilliant and should be accepted.

EDIT: original answer --

It seems that you want to essentially make a matrix by "rotating" a vector like a wiper blade from the top left corner. This produces that pattern:

```py
def wiper_blade_matrix(x):
    n = len(x)
    z = np.zeros((n, n), x.dtype)
    for k in range(-(n - 1), n):
        z[np.where(np.eye(n, k=k))] += x[abs(k):]
    return z
```

Usage:

```py
In [4]: wiper_blade_matrix(np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2]))
Out[4]:
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])

In [5]: wiper_blade_matrix(np.array([0, 0, 0, 5, 1, 2]))
Out[5]:
array([[0, 0, 0, 5, 1, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 5, 1, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 5, 1, 2],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])

In [6]: wiper_blade_matrix(np.array([3, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1]))
Out[6]:
array([[3, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```